# How to retrieve a List<Map<String, dynamic>> from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a List[Map[String, dynamic]] and save it into firestore and retrieve it. The issue is with the List, and it's giving me:  `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'`

All I really am trying to do here is have the properties below saved into the list 'classes' and retrieve their indexes to show on the screen.

#### Class

```
class Cards {
  final List<String> question;
  final List<String> answer;
  final String title;
  final String uid;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> classes;

  Cards({  this.question,  this.answer, this.uid,  this.indexTitle, this.classes });

}
```

#### Home

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> listMap = [];

 listMap.add({ 
   "title": title,
   "question": [],
   "answer": []
  });


DatabaseService(uid: userId.uid).settingUserData(listMap);
```

#### DB service

```
  // Set data to firestore db
  Future settingUserData(List<Map<String, dynamic>> listMap) async {
    return await _collref.document(uid).setData({ 
      "classes": listMap  
      });
  }



Cards _indexCardFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Cards(   
      uid: uid,  
      classes: snapshot.data["classes"], // type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'
      indexTitle: snapshot.data["indexTitle"],
      question: snapshot.data["question"],
      answer: snapshot.data["answer"], 
    );
  }
```

Comment: are you getting this error while retrieving data back ?

Comment: yes, sorry about that. I am getting this error when trying to recieve it back as a snapshot @AliHussam

Comment: Are you sure this error is in '_indexCardFromSnapshot' function where you are trying to return the card ?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine if I exclude 'classes' from '_indexCardFromSnapshot', But when I include it, that's when it throws it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because when you try to retrieve an array field back from the snapshot it only knows that the field is an array but doesn't actually know what type of data the array contains. You can use something like this:

```
Cards _indexCardFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
return Cards(   
  uid: uid,  
  classes: List<Map<String,dynamic>>.generate(
      snapshot.data["classes"].length,
      (int index) => Map<String,dynamic>
                     .from(snapshot.data["classes"].elementAt(index));
  ), 
  indexTitle: snapshot.data["indexTitle"],
  question: snapshot.data["question"],
  answer: snapshot.data["answer"], 
 );
}
```

The simplest solution is to make your classes list a `List<dynamic>`. Although it has a disadvantage of having no strong type checking at some places but it will work.

Comment: Now it's giving me  `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>`

Comment: yes, did you tried converting the temp variable to Map<String, dynamic> ? I guess you can do it using `Map<String, dynamic>.from(temp)`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I did convert it, that was the output

Comment: That is the one I used. I've seen this error before, I got it from here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16589

Comment: I tried to mimic the problem myself. And my solution seems to work fine. I'll highly appreciate if you show me your code instead.

Comment: May you please tell me what else is to show exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209964/discussion-between-ali-hussam-and-unbreachable).